# Can a lost rooted/unlocked phone be decrypted by a thief?

Tags: encryption

Someone stole my One plus 7 Pro.

It was rooted and had TWRP and Magisk 19.x ( latest subversion before 20.x dropped). I had a passcode and fingerprint set up on my phone. It was stolen at a technical convention for students. Assuming the thief has knowledge about Android can my phone's encryption be broken to give access to my files?

TWRP requires the passcode to be able to decrypt the storage, so does the phone on boot.

Any input is appreciated.

TLDR;

> Phone got stolen at a technical convention
>   Thief might have knowledge of Android
>   Running Stable Android 9 latest firmware before Stable 10.0.1
>   Running Magisk 19.x (Latest before 20.x dropped)
>   Running TWRP 3.3.1.x
>   TWRP requires the pin to decrypt

My concern, Can it be hacked/cracked to give access to the storage inside?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: My passcode was 5 digits long.

Comment: How many digits does your passcode?

Comment: The passcode is 5 digits long

Comment: In that case, there are only 90,000 passcodes (combination of digits) to try. Seems doable with any machine. TWRP provides the adb shell access through which "adb shell twrp decrypt xxxxx" can be run multiple times. The tricky thing is to get a success response back which seems doable. In other words, your data is in danger.

Answer (score 0):

If your phone is encrypted, then it cannot be decrypted without having access to the decrypt option in Settings. And since you have a fingerprint lock set up, as far as my knowledge goes, you are safe - no one will be able to access your data, even if you are rooted. Decrypting the phone externally should require extensive hacking algorithms and knowledge about the phone architecture, and I doubt anyone will spend that much time.

If, however, the thief wipes your phone (factory resets it) from TWRP, then all the data will be lost, which again means that your data will not be available to the thief, and you are still safe.